# 2005 Ford Explorer Sport Trac Exhaust System

Tags: ford, explorer, exhaust

Would I be able to fit a Spintech Pro Street 9000 series onto my 2005 Ford Explorer Sport Trac? And if so, what else would I need besides the muffler itself?